# Cannot get DownloadURL or StorageReference from DocumentReference in Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, flamelink-cms

Using the Firebase powered CMS Flamelink, there is a certain Firestore and Storage structure provided by the CMS. Images are stored in the Storage and references to it in Firestore. Firestore does provide me a DocumentReference to the Asset in the storage. But I have no idea how to get the DownloadUrl from the DocumentReference. I can retrieve the filename from the DocumentReference, but not the full path in the Storage. The full path would allow me to create a StorageReference, which has access to getDownloadUrl().

So as a workaround I am currently concatenating the filename with the storage prefix I looked up in the storage. But there must be a better way to retrieve a DownloadUrl from a DocumentReference. Otherwise it is not really a DocumentReference in my opinion. How is the correct approach to get the DownloadUrl from a DocumentReference?

```
getNewImage(DocumentReference imgRef) async {
    DocumentSnapshot imgSnapshot = await imgRef.get();
    final imageName = imgSnapshot.data['file'];

    // How to get path dynamically?
    String storagePath = 'flamelink/media/$imageName';

    StorageReference storageReference = await DataProvider.getStore();
    StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(storagePath);
    String dlurl = await ref.getDownloadURL();

    setState(() {
        _imageUrl = dlurl;
    });
}
```

I am using Flutter 1.7.8 with cloud_firestore 0.12.8 and firebase_storage 3.0.3.

Comment: any update ? Is the answer helpful ?

Comment: I sticked with the workaround and the project is over for 3 years now. Sorry, I cannot help you, I don't even have the code anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this by adding `populate` to get method.

```
const app = flamelink({
  firebaseApp
});

const res = await app.content.get({ 
  schemaKey: 'schemaName', 
  populate:[{ field: 'image'}]
}).then( ... )
```

Then image object contains `url` property with absolute path and you don't need your getNewImage() function.

Comment: Is this code for dart or javascript ?